# jQuery fadeOut when the mouse is not focused on an item or it's sibling

Tags: jquery, fade, mouseenter

I have an element with an ID of `basket`, when moused-over another element is displayed but this element is neither a child or direct sibling of the first. I hope that makes sense.

When I mouse out of the first or second element I would like the second element to fade out but I can't seem to figure out a way of explaining this to Jquery.

Heres the Jquery I'm using:-

```
$("#basket").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#cartContents").fadeIn("slow");
});
$("#basket").mouseout(function(){
    $("#cartContents").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

In the second rule I would like to add something like 'only do this bit IF the mouse IS NOT hovering over `#cartContents`'

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to achieve this/

Thanks in advance

Comment: The first part of your problem can be solved by just adding `#cartContents` to your selection like: `$("#basket, #cartContents").mouseout(function(){...`. Can you clarify the second part of your question?

Comment: I probably should clarify. #cartContents is hidden to begin with and is expected to only appear when #basket receives "focus" - in #cartContents there are a list of linked contents but when you focus on #cartContents you lose focus on #basket and the second part of the code is triggered. Hope that's clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the second question is to unbind the event when the mouse is hovering over cartContents, and re-bind it when the mouse gets out of the cartContents. just look at the bind() and unbind() methods of jquery, and use mouseenter, mouseout, or hover to bind/unbind the events.

Comment: As with the other answer here, thanks for giving me a direction to look in. bind() and unbind() are not something I'm familiar with although I've used something similar in actionscript in the past.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add hover checks to your existing code to make it work...

```
$("#basket").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#cartContents").fadeIn("slow");
});
$("#basket, #cartContents").mouseout(function(){
    if ($("#basket").is(":hover") || $("#cartContents").is(":hover")) return;
    $("#cartContents").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

It just checks the hover state of both the basket and the cart when you leave either of them and only fades out if you're not over either of them.

Here's a working example...

http://jsfiddle.net/fCxrr/1/

Comment: This is something that I can understand :) It's not working at the moment in that when the mouse leaves either element the fadeOut isn't being called, but I might be able to get it working with a little tinkering.

Comment: Check the example I just added to my answer to see it working in jsfiddle.  There must be differences somewhere that are causing you problems.

Comment: Interesting... Using Firefox your fiddle doesn't work for me, however it works as expected in Chrome.

Comment: Yep, just tried it and found it not working.  For some reason, it seems to always think #div is(":hover") is true.  I'll see if I can figure something out